# Can miners choose to accept lower fees?

Tags: transaction-fees, transaction-confirmation

Currently, transactions cost at least 0.002 XMR per kB.

If a miner includes a transaction with a lower fee, will his block be rejected by the network?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The block will not be rejected if it's included in a block mined by another miner who accepted it. See src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp, line 137 (or just after FEE_PER_KB).

This implies a miner is free to mine transactions with a fee lower than this, and any block found with such transactions will be accepted.

Comment: Good point, I made it clearer.